# String interpolation with newline character gives the wrong console.log output

Tags: react-native, expo, console.log

I have an issue in an expo project that, when using the newline character in strings, `console.log` will make a partial extraneous output at the start of the output. The strings saved in variables come out with the correct value, it's just the output of `console.log` that is wrong.

The issue only happens in the project whose `package.json` will be listed further; it does not happen in any other project that I have (same expo SDK package / RN version, ect.).

Consider the following examples:

```
const test1 = "This console.log is\nprinted incorrectly"; // length: 39
const test2 = `This console.log is\n${"also printed incorrectly"}`; // length: 44
const test3 = "This console.log is\n" + "again printed incorrectly"; // length: 45
const test4 = "This console.log is\n" + 1234; // length: 24
const test5 = ["This ", "console.log ", "is ", "\n", "printed ", "incorrectly"].join();  // length: 45
const test6 = ["This console.log is", "printed incorrectly"].join("\n"); // length: 39
const test7 = ["This", "console.log", "is", "printed", "incorrectly"].join("\n"); // length: 39
```

This is the output of the `console.log` on each of the variables:

```
console.log(test1.length); // 39
console.log(test1);
// OUTPUT:
// printed incorrectly
// This console.log is
// printed incorrectly
```

```
console.log(test2.length); // 44
console.log(test2);
// OUTPUT:
// also printed incorrectly
// This console.log is
// also printed incorrectly
```

```
console.log(test3.length); // 45
console.log(test3);
// OUTPUT:
// again printed incorrectly
// This console.log is
// again printed incorrectly
```

```
console.log(test4.length); // 24
console.log(test4);
// OUTPUT:
// Unrecognized event: 1234
// This console.log is
// 1234
```

```
console.log(test5.length); // 45
console.log(test5);
// OUTPUT:
// ,printed ,incorrectly
// This ,console.log ,is ,
// ,printed ,incorrectly
```

```
console.log(test6.length); // 39
console.log(test6);
// OUTPUT:
// printed incorrectly
// This console.log is
// printed incorrectly
```

```
console.log(test7.length); // 39
console.log(test7);
// OUTPUT:
// console.log
// is
// printed
// incorrectly
// This
// console.log
// is
// printed
// incorrectly
```

```
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    // console.log("incorrect\n" + i);
    console.log(`incorrect\n${i}`);
}
// OUTPUT
// Unrecognized event: 0
// Unrecognized event: 1
// Unrecognized event: 2
// Unrecognized event: 3
// incorrect
// 0
// incorrect
// 1
// incorrect
// 2
// incorrect
// 3
```

It is important to run those `console.log`'s separately, as outputting more variables in the same `console.log` call will result in a similar, but different behavior.

```
console.log(test1, test2, test3, test4);
// OUTPUT:
// printed incorrectly This console.log is
// also printed incorrectly This console.log is
// again printed incorrectly This console.log is
// Unrecognized event: 1234
// This console.log is
// printed incorrectly This console.log is
// also printed incorrectly This console.log is
// again printed incorrectly This console.log is
// 1234
```

The `console.log` function does not seem to have been replaced, although, I'm not sure how to test this other than by the following:

```
console.log( typeof(console.log) ); // function
console.log( console.log ); // [Function __expoConsoleLog]
```

### Environment

**package.json**

```
{
    "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "expo start",
        "android": "expo start --android",
        "ios": "expo start --ios",
        "eject": "expo eject"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "^1.0.0",
        "accordion-collapse-react-native": "^0.1.11",
        "axios": "^0.18.1",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
        "eslint": "^6.6.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.16.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.8.1",
        "expo": "^37.0.0",
        "expo-apple-authentication": "~2.1.0",
        "expo-auth-session": "^1.2.0",
        "expo-av": "~8.1.0",
        "expo-constants": "~9.0.0",
        "expo-crypto": "^8.1.0",
        "expo-facebook": "^8.1.0",
        "expo-font": "~8.1.0",
        "expo-image-picker": "~8.1.0",
        "expo-linear-gradient": "~8.1.0",
        "expo-localization": "~8.1.0",
        "expo-permissions": "~8.1.0",
        "expo-sharing": "~8.1.0",
        "math-round": "^1.0.0",
        "moment": "^2.24.0",
        "querystring": "^0.2.0",
        "react": "16.9.0",
        "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",
        "react-native-appearance": "~0.3.3",
        "react-native-check-box": "^2.1.7",
        "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^0.8.0",
        "react-native-device-info": "^5.5.6",
        "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
        "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.7.3",
        "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.3.9",
        "react-native-input-validation": "^1.2.2",
        "react-native-masked-text": "^1.12.4",
        "react-native-phone-input": "^0.2.4",
        "react-native-range-slider": "^0.1.2",
        "react-native-reanimated": "~1.7.0",
        "react-native-screens": "~2.2.0",
        "react-native-smart-statusbar": "^1.0.17",
        "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.0",
        "react-native-view-shot": "3.1.2",
        "react-navigation": "^4.0.6",
        "react-navigation-stack": "^1.9.0",
        "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.5.5",
        "toggle-switch-react-native": "^2.0.2",
        "yarn": "^1.19.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-preset-expo": "^8.1.0"
    },
    "private": true
}
```

**expo diagnostics**

```
  Expo CLI 3.20.3 environment info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 10.15.4
      Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 12.16.3 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.22.4 - ~/.yarn/bin/yarn
      npm: 6.14.4 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    IDEs:
      Xcode: 11.3/11C29 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      expo: ^37.0.0 => 37.0.8 
      react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0 
      react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz => 0.61.4 
      react-navigation: ^4.0.6 => 4.3.9
```

Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong? I have searched for issues like this, but found none that are even remotely similar to mine.
It's screwing up most of my debug output, and I have no idea why or where to look...

Perhaps the most interesting thing might be interpolating numbers with the string, that gives `Unrecognized event: #`, but searching for this does not bring any useful result.